# Sending JSON from PHP to JavaScript with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am banging my head against the wall here, and I am hoping someone can help me out.

I have an AJAX function which calls a PHP page. That page returns a JSON object, which should then be parsed and displayed to the user. Everything works fine except when the JSON object is returned, trying to parse it gives undefined.

The PHP:

```
$jsonArray= array(
                'request'  => 'this is the request',
                'response' => 'this is the response'
            );
echo json_encode($jsonArray);
```

On the Ajax side, I do the following:

```
var display=xmlHttp.responseText;
alert(display); //gives {"request":"this is the request","response":"This is the response"}
alert(display.request); //gives undefined
```

Am I missing something obvious? Pasting the same string directly into a JavaScript variable seems to work fine...

Comment: don't forget to send the correct headers with your JSON object (text/json). text/html will work because both are text, but it's good practice to send the correct mime type.

Comment: @zzzzBov: No, according to RFC 4627, the correct JSON MIME type is `application/json`. You can use the PHP code `header('Content-type: application/json');` before the echo statement to set this.

Comment: @idealmachine apologies, i didn't look up the correct mime type. My point still stands that text/html will work because both are text.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to parse the json string. JSON.parse should do the tricks. If it's not working, there's probably a problème with the object you encoded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the JSON data returned from your server.  There are many libraries to do this such as:

[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/),

Comment: Documentation for jQuery's `$.parseJSON`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 1):

```
var myObject = eval('(' + display + ')');
```

Answer (score 0):

`display` is a string.  you will need to use

```
var obj = eval(display)
```

but eval() is not as safe as using JSON.parse().

Comment: Please validate before parsing script from an external source. This is a leading cause in cross-site scripting (XSS).

Comment: The code won't work if an object is returned instead of an array. Parentheses are needed for JavaScript to disambiguate between a) object literal notation, and b) a block of statements.